# Outlook 2010: How to top-quote initial message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

If I have a message in Outlook 2010 whose body is "Hello, World." and I reply, I get...

> [caret position]
>
> mysig | myphone | my name
>
> > Hello, World.

What's the easiest way to get that to default to...

> > Hello, World.
>
> [caret position]
>
> mysig | myphone | my name

[This](http://home.in.tum.de/~jain/software/outlook-quotefix/) looked hopeful, but the last version was released in 2006 (before Word became the "rich" editor for Outlook, right?).

Comment: I'm painfully using a really slapdash utility I wrote for this for now: [Quotify](http://rufwork.com/projects/wackApps/).

Comment: There seems to be no standard setting for it at least. Is there a specific reason behind wanting this? I mean, while it is more logical to have the newest conversation at the bottom, the practice of adding it to the top is widely accepted. To not confuse your receivers, try to stick to that custom. Especially in long conversations, the history will be jumbled if others add things to the top of the mail.

Comment: I usually want to emphasize something in the email to which I'm replying, and respond directly to that edited content. Putting the quote on top helps accomplish that. Top-quoting is conventional enough that other major clients ([eg, Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reply-above-or-below-quoted-text)) provide it, and Outlook is scriptable enough I thought it'd be possible, if not in the settings somewhere. [Gruber explains this practice exceptionally well](http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/on_top).